# Reading a file and converting it into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have this text file:

#### this is `name_of_liquid(string)=amount(int)`

```
liquid1=200

liquid2=20

liquid_X_= empty

liquid_3= 3000
```

now, the name does not really matter however the amount does. It has to be an int.
If it is any other type beside int the program would raise an exception

Here is my code/ pseudocode:

```
#opening the file
d={}

try:
  dic = {}
  with open('accounts.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
        (key , val) = line.split()
        d[key] = int(val)
#except ValueError:
#    print('The value for', key,'is', value,' which is not a number!')
```

the except block is commented because that is my pseudocode and how I planed in handling the
error, but when I run this code without using exception handling, I get an error of 'not enough values to unpack'
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `line.split('=')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380491/15080854 (Modulo your field separator)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
f = open("acounts.txt", "r")
dict = {}

try:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split("=")
        dict[line[0]] = int(line[1])
except:
print("Invalid value for key.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split the lines with `=` as delimiter and strip the list to get rid of extra whitespaces.

I personally think that the try catch block should be used while adding elements to the dictionary.

The following code should work for your problem.

```
d = {}
with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        (key , val) = map(str.strip,line.split("="))
        try:
            d[key] = int(val)
        except ValueError:
            print('The value for', key,'is', val,' which is not a number!')
```

Comment: can you please explain the use of the map. I tried searching it up and learning more about it but I cant seem to understand it and how you implemented it. Thank you

Comment: map applies a function to every element in an iterable (list, tuple, range, etc) so the syntax of map is `map(function, iterable)`. Example refer the following code:

`nums = [1,2,3]`
`print(list(map(lambda x:x*2,nums))) # Output is [2, 4, 6]`

so for your solution `line.split` creates a list and the `map` executes the `str.strip` function  on every string in the list to remove whitespaces and returns a map object you can also convert that map into a list using `list(map(str.strip,line.split("=")))`